# How to inject mocks while testing classes using CDI in production

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, cdi

I am programming in a Java SE environment using WELD-SE for dependency injection. Therefore dependencies of a class look something like this:

```
public class ProductionCodeClass {
    @Inject
    private DependencyClass dependency;
}
```

When writing a unit test for this class I am creating a mock for `DependencyClass` and as I don't want to start a complete CDI environment for every test I run, I "inject" the mock manually:

```
import static TestSupport.setField;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

public class ProductionCodeClassTest {
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mockedDependency = mock(DependencyClass.class);
        testedInstance = new ProductionCodeClass();
        setField(testedInstance, "dependency", mockedDependency);
    }
}
```

The statically imported method `setField()` I have written myself in a class with tools I use in testing:

```
public class TestSupport {
    public static void setField(
                                final Object instance,
                                final String field,
                                final Object value) {
        try {
            for (Class classIterator = instance.getClass();
                 classIterator != null;
                 classIterator = classIterator.getSuperclass()) {
                try {
                    final Field declaredField =
                                classIterator.getDeclaredField(field);
                    declaredField.setAccessible(true);
                    declaredField.set(instance, value);
                    return;
                } catch (final NoSuchFieldException nsfe) {
                    // ignored, we'll try the parent
                }
            }

            throw new NoSuchFieldException(
                      String.format(
                          "Field '%s' not found in %s",
                          field,
                          instance));
        } catch (final RuntimeException re) {
            throw re;
        } catch (final Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

What I don't like about this solution is, that I need this helper over and over in any new project. I already packaged it as a Maven project I can add as a test dependency to my projects.

But isn't there something ready made in some other common library I am missing? Any comments on my way of doing this in general?

Comment: Use constructor injection.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Mockito supports this out of the box:

```
public class ProductionCodeClassTest {

    @Mock
    private DependencyClass dependency;

    @InjectMocks
    private ProductionCodeClass testedInstance;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        testedInstance = new ProductionCodeClass();
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

}
```

The [`@InjectMocks`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.47/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) annotation will trigger injection of classes or interfaces mocked in the test class, in this case `DependencyClass`:

> Mockito tries to inject by type (using name in case types are the same). Mockito does not throw anything when injection fails - you will have to satisfy the dependencies manually.

Here, I am also using the `@Mock` annotation instead of calling `mock()`. You could still use `mock()`, but I prefer using annotations.

As a side note, there are reflection tools available, which supports the functionality you implemented in `TestSupport`. One such example is [`ReflectionTestUtils`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html).

---

Perhaps better still is to use [constructor injection](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/injection.html#_injection_points):

```
public class ProductionCodeClass {

    private final DependencyClass dependency;

    @Inject
    public ProductionCodeClass(DependencyClass dependency) {
        this.dependency = dependency;
    }
}
```

The main advantage here is that it is clear what classes the class depends on, and that it cannot easily be constructed without providing all the dependencies. Also, it allows the injected class to be final.

By doing this, `@InjectMocks` is not necessary. Instead, just create the class by providing the mock as a parameter to the constructor:

```
public class ProductionCodeClassTest {

    @Mock
    private DependencyClass dependency;

    private ProductionCodeClass testedInstance;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        testedInstance = new ProductionCodeClass(dependency);
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, that's actually what I was locking for. Already tried it and the results look very good. I couldn't find this … ;-)
Im am not using Spring so just adding it to get ReflectionTestUtils might be a bit heavy weighted. But thank you for this suggestion anyway too.

Comment: @Magnilex : Have you considered adding either `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` or `@Rule public MockitoRule rule ...` to your code to make it complete?

Comment: @Henrik The code is complete. `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` would be an alternative though. However, this answer explains OP:s question, the question is not asking for alternatives on how to run a mockito based JUnit test.

Comment: @Magnilex: Ah, ok. I assumed that Mockito had to be invoked more explicitly. Thanks for replying.

Comment: For Junit5 you can annotate the test with `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` instead of `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`. `MockitoExtension` can be found in the Maven dependency `org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter`.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative when mockitos build in functions do not suffice: Try [needle4j.org](http://needle4j.org)

It's a injection/mock framework that allows injection of mocks and concrete instances and also supports postConstruct for lifecycle simulation.

```
 public class ProductionCodeClassTest {

    @Rule
    public final NeedleRule needle = new NeedleRule();

    // will create productionCodeClass and inject mocks by default
    @ObjectUnderTest(postConstruct=true)
    private ProductionCodeClass testedInstance;

    // this will automatically be a mock
    @Inject
    private AServiceProductionCodeClassDependsOn serviceMock;

    // this will be injected into ObjectUnderTest 
    @InjectIntoMany
    private ThisIsAnotherDependencyOfProdcutionCodeClass realObject = new ThisIsAnotherDependencyOfProdcutionCodeClass ();

    @Test
    public void test_stuff() {
         ....
    }

}
```

Comment: Nice! Is there a sample project/test suite, by any chance? Something like JMockit's sample (https://github.com/jmockit/jmockit1/tree/master/samples/petclinic) would be ideal.

Comment: Well, there are a few examples based on 2.2, but we didn't migrate them to 2.3 so far. But it might be helpful: https://github.com/needle4j/needle/tree/master/src/examples